# Kemal configuration using blocks

Tags: crystal-lang, kemal

Kemal currently allows setting configuration options via:

`Kemal.config.env = "development"
Kemal.config.port = "3456"`

I want to do something like with a block:

`configuration do |config|
  config.env = "development"
  config.port = "3456"
  ...
end`

Is this even possible?
Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe, you could utilize [Object#tap](https://devdocs.io/crystal/api/0.24.1/object#tap(&block)-instance-method) method like this:

```
Kemal.config.tap do |config|
  config.env = "development"
  config.port = "3456"
  ...
end
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you!